# Show values of a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataTable` being created:

```
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
```

After populating the `DataTable` with some data, I'm trying to show its data in a `DataGrid`:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = datatable.DefaultView;
```

My `DataGrid` has this configuration:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="124" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="41,92,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335" 
          DataContext="{Binding}" ColumnHeaderHeight="20" RowHeight="20" />
```

Although my `DataTable` has the expected data in it, the `DataGrid` is empty.

I'm sure there's something wrong with my code, but I can't find what. How can I correctly show data in the `DataGrid` using data from a `DataTable` in WPF?

Comment: Try setting the `dataGrid1.ItemSource = yoursource`

Comment: DataContext vs ItemSource http://www.vofoxsolutions.com/itemssource-vs-data-context/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` in your `DataGrid` you should also use `<DataGrid.Columns>` to get full control of which columns are shown and how their data should be viewed and edited. Or set the `AutoGenerateColumns` to `True` so that the `DataGrid` will automatically generate appropriate columns for you:

```
AutoGenerateColumns="True"
```

Also you should set your `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` instead of `DataContext`:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = datatable.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn column;
DataRow row;
DataView view;
column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.ColumnName = "id";
table.Columns.Add(column);
column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "name";
table.Columns.Add(column);

// Create new DataRow objects and add to DataTable.    
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    row = table.NewRow();
    row["id"] = i;
    row["name"] = "Name " + i.ToString();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

Remove `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` Or Set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`